# Remove horizondal scroll

Tags: css, sass, styles

Is there any way to remove the horizontal scroll ?
There is no content towards the right but the area remains blank and scrolling comes .

[image]

The styles for modal are :

```
.ticketModal {
  width: 1000px;
  min-width: 1000px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to post a code or within this post itself or at some other place?
Looks like the problem is with the parent container. 
If you want to hide a scroll only for this particular screen then add ```overflow-x: hidden;``` by tracing which parent is getting overflowed then adding a property ```hidden``` on that particular div should work.
Or else you can place overflow property on body eg: ```body {overflow-x: hidden}```.
However, this will add on complete application so be caution!!

Comment: Thanks. You're right. The problem was with the other elements styling. I gave a min width and left properties which made the overflow. Now its solved after removing styling from those elements.

Answer (score 1):

You should add in your css `overflow-x: hidden;` to your main div or class, this will help you to remove horizontal scroll

Comment: Tried that but that doesnt seem to be the issue.

Comment: then what is the issue?, please clarify. [ntk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8417783/ntk)

Comment: The problem was with other elements styling with the same parent div. Had to remove the min width and left properties to get it corrected.

Comment: He already has `overflow: hidden;` in the code

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the horizontal scroll in the entire app. Simply add

```
*{
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

This will remove the horizontal scroll for all the DOM elements